# Toplevel() and Label out put from For loop - Python 2

Tags: python, user-interface, label

I want to create a gui sub window that could look like this, which lists a live feedback for the top teams and also giving them a numbering.

So I have done for loop function to number them and Label them out, which works fine when run with nothing but the code but I'm having trouble making it run on the new window that is opened from main window.

[image]

```
import io
import base64
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
from re import findall
from urllib2 import urlopen


def epl_Window():
    epl = tk.Toplevel()
    epl.title('Top Ten EPL Team 2016')
    url = "http://i.imgur.com/3znCRqH.gif"
    image_byte1 = urlopen(url).read()
    data_stream1 = io.BytesIO(image_byte1)
    pil_image1 = Image.open(data_stream1)
    w, h = pil_image.size
    tk_image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image1)
    label1 = tk.Label(epl, image=tk_image1, bg='black')
    label1.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
    epl.geometry("500x700")

    for index, value in enumerate(EPL_10, start=1):
        Label(epl, text=str(index)).grid(row=index, column=1, sticky='W')
        Label(epl, text=value).grid(row=index, column=2, sticky='W')

    epl.mainloop()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Top Ten Lists")

url = "http://i.imgur.com/H1sURuR.gif"
image_bytes = urlopen(url).read()
# internal data file
data_stream = io.BytesIO(image_bytes)
# open as a PIL image object
pil_image = Image.open(data_stream)
# optionally show image info
# get the size of the image
w, h = pil_image.size

### convert PIL image object to Tkinter PhotoImage object
tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)

# put the image on a typical widget
label = tk.Label(root, image=tk_image, bg='brown')
label.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

#BUTTON
EPL_B = Button(root, text='EPL Teams', width=10, command=epl_Window)
EPL_B.pack(anchor = "w", side = LEFT)

#EPL RANK
url = 'http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/premier-league/table'
EPL_contents = urlopen(url).read()
EPL_Ranking = findall("'>(\w* ?\w*)</a>", EPL_contents)
EPL_10= EPL_Ranking[:10]

root.mainloop()
```

I think there is problem with def new window toplevel() but not sure how to change it to load. Running it make program crash

Answer (score 1):

So it crashes when you click on the button which opens the TopLevel?
Without a traceback this is very difficult to answer, but my guess is that the line

```
epl.mainloop()
```

causes the crash. Even if it doesn't, you don't need to call it. There is usually only one mainloop at a time on your root widget.